# Absolute static url in template tags

Tags: django, static, templatetags

I'm trying to setup a filter which takes a string value and returns an image element, but I cannot make it to return the absolute one, just the relative one by hard-coding the url.

I would like to use something like:

```
return '<img src="{% static 'img/flags/country_flag.jpg'>"
```

Here is my code:

## ... extras.py

```
@register.filter(name="flag")
def flag(language):
    if language == 'fr':
        return '<img src="static/img/flags/french.jpg" class="flag">'
    elif language == 'ge':
        return '<img src="static/img/flags/german.jpg" class="flag">'
```

## html

```
<td class="subtitle-flag"> {{subtitle.language | flag | safe}}</td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it required for you to return the entire image object instead of just the name of the file? If it's not, you could try:

## ... extras.py

```
@register.filter(name="flag")
def flag(language):
    if language == 'fr':
        return 'french'
    elif language == 'ge':
        return 'german'
```

## html

```
<td class="subtitle-flag">
    {% with flag_name=subtitle.language|flag|safe %}
    <img src="{% static 'img/flags/'|add:flag_name|add:'.jpg' %}" class="flag" />
    {% endwith %}
</td>
```

Read the docs for more information about the [`add` filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#add) and [`with` tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#with).